# Apex 5 Help changing form value before the Insert process

Tags: apex

I'm taking user input in the form of a date picker which requires it to have the following format visible to the user after his select: dd-mm-yyyy so I'm using a Format Mask with that value(dd-mm-yyyy)

However, the database column is a varchar2 of only 8 characters, not 10 and I need to get rid of the '-' before the insert.

Right now I'm using Database Column as Source-Type with Column_name in the Source value or expression field.

and

I'm attempting to use substr(:P19_Itemname,1,2)+ substr(:P19_Itemname,4,2)+substr(:P19_Itemname,7,4); in the Post Calculation Computation area which is obviously not working.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: Everything works fine if I use ddmmyyyy in the Format Mask but the user doesn't like it.
Also the submit process is the basic Automatic Row Processing (DML)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the column data type like date and then try